# Keyword search results don't show user rep

Tags: support, bug, search

Today I noticed that keyword search results don't show user rep as they do with `[tag]` searches

### Searching by keyword search only shows username and date:

[image: search by keyword]

### Searching by tag on the other hand still shows user stats:

[image]

Is this a bug or by design? And if the latter, why?

Comment: I don't think it ever displayed the user's reputation.

Comment: @JL2210 - I used to regularly search "opencart" (the word not the tag) to look for questions to answer, and one of my primary filters is to shy away from questions by people with 1 rep.  I'm pretty sure I was able to see rep in the past but perhaps staff can answer this more definitively. At any rate, I don't see why the format of the search results should be any different.